# "Browse", "Open file", "Select files" dialog not working

Tags: windows

All of the sudden the method by apps open the "select a file" dialog stopped working. For instance if I go to https://uploadfiles.io/, clicking on it does nothing, but the drag and drop works.

This is happening for apps as well, for example I just needed to resync my Google Drive and change the folder location, clicking in "browse" to select a folder does nothing. However, going to Notepad and file > open file works.

I've been searching for a while for the method, .dll, or something that is responsible for this without success. Anyone with a similar issue or more knowledge than what I have can point me in the right direction?

I'm not a naive English speaker so I am not sure if I'm not finding anything because I am not using the right names to search for it.

Windows 10 64b INSIDER PREVIEW FAST RING

Comment: Is it broken for every browser on your machine?

Comment: Try different internet browser, such as Chrome, Firefox, etc. ?

Comment: and try to ask in [super user](https://superuser.com/)..

Comment: @zerkms it os broken for every app and browser on my machine that uses that "browse" / "select a file" method.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue. It started somewhere between Friday and today. (Computer was shutdown for two weeks until friday night and before shutting down the problem did not exist.) I suspect some update. In addition to the mentioned issue I have trouble downloading files through Chrome. Edge and IE are downloading fine. Firefox will be installed to test this. It is consistent which apps are (not) allowed to spawn new windows. Apps in 'Program Files' seem OK while those in 'Program Files(x86)' differ. Of those in the (x86) folder OpenOffice is allowed to open a browse window, Adobe Reader is not. KeePass is allowed to open files, EventGhost is not. (changing install folder does not make a difference).

Since it is not clear how long this issue has been around I am hesitant to do a system restore. Also I believe that is a bandaid, not a solution. I am on the Fast Ring of updates.